# How to auto run code cleanup profile on save with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to create a C# based project. I would like to format and cleanup my file every time I save a file.

Most instructions states that I should be able to achieve that by going to

> "Tools" > "Options" > "Text Editor" > "Code Cleanup". Add a check in
> the "Run Code Cleanup profile on Save." Be sure to select the
> appropriate profile you want to execute automatically whenever you
> save!

The source of the instructions can be found [here](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2022/01/11/code-cleanup-on-save.aspx)

But I don't see "Code Cleanup" under "Text Editor" tab. How can I apply the code clean up profile automatically on save in Visual Studio 2022?

I am using Visual Studio 2022 v17.0.4

Also, is there a way to auto apply the rule [csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#namespace-options) to a code profile?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to run code cleanup profile on save, you can refer to the following steps:

This is a new feature in Visual Studio 2022 17.1. You need to update to Visual Studio 2022 17.1 first.

Then you can navigate to Tools > Options > Text Editor > Code Cleanup. Add a check to “Run Code Cleanup profile on Save”.

[image]

If you want to auto-apply the rule `csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped` to a code profile, you can refer to this link to edit the .editorconfig file: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/create-portable-custom-editor-options?view=vs-2022

You can see the example .editorconfig file from here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/style-rules/formatting-rules#namespace-options

```
[*.cs]
csharp_style_namespace_declarations = file_scoped
```

Answer (score 0):

As to the Run Code Cleanup on Save, the article addresses that in the first sentence:

> One nifty little feature in the brand-new **Visual Studio 2022 17.1 Preview 2** is automatic Code Cleanup on Save.

So you'll need to update to a 17.1 version to get the feature.

Regarding the rule for file scoped namespaces, I don't think Code Cleanup will handle that, but if you set it in .editorconfig there should be a code action (aka "lightbulb action") that will fix it up in the current file/project/solution.  So it should be a one-time invocation (apply to the whole solution), and then future files should respect it when they are created based on the .editorconfig setting.